# Gitlab on a Raspberry with Apache on subdirectory

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, gitlab, raspberry-pi2

I am using an raspberry pi(debian-wheezy) with Apache and now I wanted to add gitlab.

For testing I installed gitlab on a clean debian os and everything went well.
On the "live" system I installed gitlab as well, but I am stuck at setting gitlab as subdirectory/redirect.

I set my relative url at the `gitlab.rb` to `/gitlab`. I tried to set a system link to the gitlab root, but I get a `not found` Error.

Answer (score 4):

**Read my updated answer bellow this one if you want to go and install Gitlab**

Wow, 3 months late, but if anyone runs into this post, here's what worked for me:

I was using Gitlab on my old server setup, but On the Pi i wanted something lighter (it only has 1GB of Ram). I found Gogs, It works very similarly and the installation wasn't too bad actually, took a while but yeah.
to get Gogs going you have to install Golang, wich could take about an hour to build so make sure you have time.

> Install git and Mysql/PortegeSql first.
>   Makes sure you have apache or Nginx installed already
>   you'll need to have Git global set up already, it's easier that way.
>   a good amount of time

let's setup some packages we need:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mercurial gcc libc6-dev
```

And now we clone from the repo

```
hg clone -u default https://code.google.com/p/go $HOME/go
```

cd into and build GO

```
cd $HOME/go/src
./all.bash
```

it'll take a while, so Go do something else lol

Once that's complete we just need to add it to our PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
go version
```

and If you didn't get any errors we are good to Go! (lol)

now to install Gogs!

let's make a directory where all of our repos are going to be, mine is on an external device since I don't wanna run out of space on my Pi.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/MyDrive/Repos
sudo mkdir ~/gopath
```

give those files the correct permissions

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /mnt/MyDrive/Repos
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/gopath
```

Cd into the home directory and set the paths for the system:

```
cd ~
echo 'export GOROOT=$HOME/go' >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath' >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

let's download the dependencies n stuff

```
go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs
```

use git pull to get all the files off the repo.
aaaand build!

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gogits/gogs
go build
```

it's gonna take a little bit. once built make sure you make the database for it with either portegeSql or Mysql, I used mysql since I already had it installed on my system.

lets change the root directory of the repos to the repo folder we made earlier

```
sudo nano $GOPATH/src/github.com/gogits/gogs/custom/conf/app.ini
```

and inside we add

```
[repository]
ROOT = /mnt/MyDrive/Repos
```

and you can also add the databse config from here, but you'll do it from the browser so no need.

let's test it out!!!

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gogits/gogs
./gogs web
```

if you don't see any errors then you, my friend, are good to go!

another thing. by default Gogs uses port 3000, in my configuration I use apache webserver which i already have configured. once the set up is complete use your handy dandy browser and headover to `yoursite.com:3000` to get to the configuration for gogs.

I think that's it. Let me know if I missed anything.

Sources:

[Gogs from source config](http://gogs.io/docs/installation/install_from_source.html)

[Gogs detailed config from source](http://gogs.io/docs/advanced/configuration_for_source_builds.md)

[Gogs on rasp pi](http://blog.meinside.pe.kr/Gogs-on-Raspberry-Pi/)

[installing Golang on rasp pi](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/25/installing-go-on-the-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I got some errors at the end when build GO with "./all.bash" but gogs worked like a charm on my raspberry :) Thank's GeneralCan!

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of headaches I actually managed to install a full version of Gitlab on my raspberry pi2 model B.

would I recommend it? not really lol, this thing is a HOG, it will take all your ram... literally... why do it? it was a fun little experiment, and it actually wasn't too difficult to put together as the Gitlab team has put together a pretty good tutorial when it comes to compiling from source... this is not for the feint of heart.

I'm actually running my dev repo from here :) so far so good lol.

so, I'm assuming you're using ubuntu core image and not raspian. there's already a package put together for raspian here : [Gitlab for raspian](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/).
if you don't have the image, here's the one I used: [link to ubuntu download image](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/xenial/ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz.torrent), and here's the URL to the site: https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/

so, once you have your image installed and you've set up your user account...

1- run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the latest version of everything in your system.

2- now we need to extend the system over the whole sd card because the original image size is only 2.something GBs.
you can [follow the instructions from Steve Robillard](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/501#501?newreg=82e5afa8d58046379aebc9b0e7b986d1) dude knows what he's saying.

3- once that's done we need to create some swap, 1GB of ram will not be enough. [you can follow these instructions right here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I chose to make my swap 4GB, swapinness 60 and pressure 50. read up on these.

now that we have all the easy stuff out of the way go here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

make sure you read the whole guide before beginning to hack away at stuff, I broke my installation about 3 times... it sucked.

when you get to step 3, installing Go lang. you need to grab the armv6 tar.gz here: https://golang.org/dl/

and do:

```
curl --remote-name --progress LINK-TO-TAR.GZ

sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf YOUR-TAR-FILE.tar.gz

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/go/bin/{go,godoc,gofmt} /usr/local/bin/
```

and then:

```
rm YOUR-TAR-FILE.tar.gz
```

when you get to the part about setting up Nginx make sure that you do not use port 8080 because unicorn uses it and gitlab will throw an error page when you try to access it.

also, whenever you change a setting in gitlab.yml make sure you run

`sudo service gitlab restart`

and

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`

so that your changes are verified.

it takes forever, but I learned a ton of stuff by searching and pulling things together here and there. let me know if you have any questions.

sources:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

https://golang.org/dl/

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/how-can-i-resize-my-root-partition/501#501?newreg=82e5afa8d58046379aebc9b0e7b986d1

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04